# Matching Data Between Two Workbooks and Paste Data Based on

Tags: excel, vba, matching

The situation I am dealing with is one where there is a table with account numbers in the first column, amounts in the fifth column, and 'F' or 'P' in the seventh column. The account numbers match account numbers located on another workbook in the first column. If, in the seventh column on the table (In the source workbook, there is an 'F,' the value should be copied, matched, and pasted on the same row in the forth column on the target workbook. If there is a 'P,' the value should be matched and pasted on the same row in the fifth column on the target workbook. The code works but it does not distingwish between F or P. It pastes all of the values in both colums.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i&
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range

Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set w1 = Workbooks("HF Pricing Template1").Sheets("Tables")
Set w2 = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set SrchRng = Range("Table3[Price_Type]")

For Each cell In SrchRng
If cell.Value = "P" Then

i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("M5:M" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 5).Value
        End If
    Next


 i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w2.Range("A2:A" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, 3).Value = Dic(key)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If

Next cell
For Each cell In SrchRng
If cell.Value = "P" Then

   i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w1.Range("M5:M" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 5).Value
        End If
    Next


    i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For Each oCell In w2.Range("A2:A" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, 4).Value = Dic(key)
            End If
        Next
    Next
 End If

 Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this complete re-write.

Read the comments for explanation

```
'compare text (ignore case)
option compare text 

dim source_wb as workbook
dim dest_wb as workbook

dim source_ws as worksheet
dim dest_ws as worksheet

'set workbooks/sheets
set source_wb = workbooks("HF Pricing Template1")
set source_ws = source_wb.worksheets("Table")

set dest_wb = workbooks("Book1")
set dest_ws = dest_wb.worksheets("Sheet1")

dim source_lr as integer
dim dest_lr as integer

'get last row of data in each sheet for column 1 (the account numbers)
'checks for account number list in column "a" change where applicable
source_lr = source_ws.cells(rows.count, "M").end(xlup).row
dest_lr = dest_ws.cells(rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row


'this starts checking for account numbers at row 2 change where applicable
for source_row = 2 to source_lr
    ''this start checking for account numbers at row 2 change where applicable
    for dest_row = 2 to dest_lr
        'check if account numbers match
        ' change column as applicable 
        if source_ws.cells(source_row, "M") = dest_ws.cells(dest_row, "A") then
            'if column 7  in source contains p then copy to column 4 in dest ws
            'change column where applicable
            if source_ws.cells(source_row, "S") = "p" then
                dest_ws.cells(dest_row,"D") = source_ws.cells(source_row, "R")
                exit for
  
            'if column 7  in source contains f then copy to column 5 in dest ws
            ' change column where applicable
            elseif source_ws.cells(source_row, "S") = "f" then
                dest_ws.cells(dest_row, "E") = source_ws.cells(source_row, "R")
                exit for
            end if
        end if
    next dest_row
next source_row
```

Please note - i'm not at a windows machine and cant test this right now, but it should work as expected.

Comment: How can I thank you? I just have one question on your amazing code. The source workbook had a table with a range of M5 to S17. Does this logic capture that?

Comment: I've amended it to have coloumn letters , you can change where applicable

Comment: What it does is check for the length of the table so it can be any length BUT you need need to enter the column letters your self to match your worksheets

Comment: Well, the data on the source workbook sits on a table between M5:S17. This table contains seven columns. The 'M' column contains the account numbers, which should match column 'A' on the destination workbook. Column 'R' includes values that we are trying to copy, and column 'S' contains the P or F letters. We need the Macro to look in the source workbook in column 'M' and match it with the destination and copy the value in column 'R,' and depending on F or P, it should copy the same row either the third or fourth column respectively.

Comment: Try that ammendment

Comment: Lewis, look at what I posted as an answer to provide you an idea of what  I am dealing with.

Comment: I've changed my answer, test it and let me know please.

Comment: Lewis, it is still not working. The only thing I am changing from your code is `for source_row = 2 to source_lr` (I change it from a 2 to a 5 because the data starts on the 5th row). I am also not adding `option compare text`. The first code I posted transferred the data well. Now, the code runs but nothing transfers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220117/discussion-between-mamamia93-and-lewis-morris).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim source_wb As Workbook
Dim dest_wb As Workbook

Dim source_ws As Worksheet
Dim dest_ws As Worksheet

'set workbooks/sheets
Set source_wb = Workbooks("HF Pricing Template1")
Set source_ws = source_wb.Worksheets("Tables")

Set dest_wb = Workbooks("Book1")
Set dest_ws = dest_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim source_lr As Integer
Dim dest_lr As Integer

'get last row of data in each sheet for column 1 (the account numbers)
'checks for account number list in column "a" change where applicable
source_lr = source_ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
dest_lr = dest_ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


'this starts checking for account numbers at row 2 change where applicable
For source_row = 5 To source_lr
''this start checking for account numbers at row 2 change where applicable
For dest_row = 2 To dest_lr
    'check if account numbers match
    ' change column as applicable
    If source_ws.Cells(source_row, "M") = dest_ws.Cells(dest_row, "A") Then
        'if column 7  in source contains p then copy to column 4 in dest ws
        'change column where applicable
        If source_ws.Cells(source_row, "S") = "P" Then
            dest_ws.Cells(dest_row, "D") = source_ws.Cells(source_row, "M")
            Exit For
        'if column 7  in source contains f then copy to column 5 in dest ws
        ' change column where applicable
        ElseIf source_ws.Cells(source_row, "S") = "F" Then
            dest_ws.Cells(dest_row, "E") = source_ws.Cells(source_row, "M")
            Exit For

        End If
     End If
   Next
 Next
```